# Solving tridiagonal matrices where the top left element is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, curves

If I have a matrix like this:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr|r}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & y_1-y_0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & y_0-y_1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & y_1-y_0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & y_2-y_1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & y_1-y_2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & y_2-y_1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & y_3-y_2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right] \\
$$

How can I solve it using the tridiagonal algorithm? The first step in all of the versions of the algorithm that I have seen involve dividing by zero. For example: [http://www.cfd-online.com/Wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm_-*TDMA*(Thomas_algorithm)](http://www.cfd-online.com/Wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm_-_TDMA_(Thomas_algorithm))

Comment: The first row implies that $x_2=0$.  Could we delete that column (and the first row), then use the algorithm to solve for the remaining variables?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Thank you. I have no idea why I did not think of that earlier.